# How can I put the mat card title and subtitle in the same line?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular material, this is the html code:

```
<mat-card>
   <mat-card-header *ngFor="let club of result[0]">
      <mat-card-title>{{club.clubName}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>Club</mat-card-subtitle>
   </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

I want to this:

[image: Line]

Comment: It seems that it is more css related question. Just check the output in the browser console and style the elements with css. You can use display inline or display flex or float - you can find many different ways.

Comment: which version of material are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the CSS or HTML structure adjustment:

**Using CSS:**
Take mat-card-header as a parent to write the CSS and put `display: flex`

**Using HTML**
Put card subtitle inside the card-title tag

Please let me know if you have any question

Comment: `mat-card-header { display: flex; }` that's good?

Comment: Yup, it should Or you can define some class to the card-header

Comment: I did it but it's still in 2 line...

Comment: Can you please share the whole CSS of this: <mat-card>
   <mat-card-header *ngFor="let club of result[0]">
      <mat-card-title>{{club.clubName}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>Club</mat-card-subtitle>
   </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>>

Comment: The css code is the same as the one I sent before

Comment: Material does the design, so css file is empty

Comment: Try this: mat-card-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

Comment: I put it in a div and defined a class: .name { display: flex; } it works but they are in a row but not in a line...

Comment: May be parent html tag have the padding

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class .my-card to mat-card elementzand target the inner elements

**Angular 14**

```css
::ng-deep .my-card .mat-card-header .mat-card-header-text {
  display: flex;
}

::ng-deep .my-card .mat-card-header .mat-card-header-text .mat-card-subtitle {
  margin: 0 0 12px !important;
}
```

**Angular 15**

```css
::ng-deep .my-card .mat-mdc-card-header .mat-mdc-card-header-text {
  display: flex;
}

::ng-deep .my-card .mat-mdc-card-header .mat-mdc-card-header-text .mat-mdc-card-subtitle {
  margin: 0 0 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: `<mat-card class="my-card">...</mat-card>` that's good?